# Inserting svg dynamically into html

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have the following HTML, and I'm trying to make it cool by adding graphics with JS:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Card Game</title>
    <script src="script1.js"></script>
    <style>
        button{
            width: 200px;
            height: 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="buttonDiv">
        <button id="playgame" onclick="playGame()">Are you feeling lucky?</button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

In my script, the playGame() function opens up this space, where the svg's are images of the face of cards:

```js
const images =
  { '2_S': '<svg>.....</svg>'
  , '2_D':'<svg>.....</svg>...'
  //, '2_H' ....through the deck of cards
  }
const ranks = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"];
const suits = ['S', 'C', 'D', 'H'];
// and
    let rank, suit;
    let cardArray = [];

    let card = function (rankarg, suitarg, imagearg) {
        this.rank = rankarg;
        this.suit = suitarg;
        this.image = imagearg;

        // this.isDrawn = isDrawn;
    }
    let buildCardArray = function () {
        for (let rankIndex = 0; rankIndex < 13; rankIndex++) {
            rank = ranks[rankIndex];
            for (let suitIndex = 0; suitIndex < 4; suitIndex++) {
                suit = suits[suitIndex];
                let stringBuilder = "" + `${rank}` + "_" + `${suit}`;
                let img = new Image();
                img.src = images[`${stringBuilder}`];
                let thisCard = new card(rank, suit, img);
                thisCard.toString = function () { return stringBuilder; }
                cardArray.push(thisCard);
            }
        }
    }
    buildCardArray();
    let masterDiv = document.createElement('div');
    let button = document.getElementById('buttonDiv');
    button.append(masterDiv);
    let imgDiv;
    function placeImage(index) {       
        imgDiv = document.createElement('div');
        let content = cardArray[index].image.src;        
        imgDiv.innerHTML = content;        
    }
    placeImage(30);
    masterDiv.appendChild(imgDiv);
    }
```

I've tried what feels like a million different things, including using a `<canvas>` element. Right now it outputs:

```
http://localhost:56803/%3Csvg%20width=%22133px%22%20height=%22191px%22%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20viewBox=%220%200%20147.67%20213.53%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type=%22text/css%22%3E.cls-1%7Bfill:#fff;stroke:#010101;stroke-width:2 ...many lines of code for one image </svg>
```

why is it messing up my string with the local host thing, and even when I try to chop the local host thing off it just posts the string rather than converts it.

A previous SO post response suggested to do this (adapted slightly):

```
content = new DOMParser().parseFromString(cardArray[index].image.src, "image/svg+xml");
```

it outputs: `[Object XMLDocument].`

BTW just posting that same string in my HTML generates the image correctly on the page.

I'm a newbie coder, especially to web stuff. What don't I get, and how do I fix?

Comment: There is a ready made Card Web Component: https://cardmeister.github.io and https://dev.to/dannyengelman/how-to-cheat-with-web-components-295o

Answer (score 0):

I can see what confuses. When setting the src attribute on an `<img>` with a string of SVG you need to add "data:image/svg+xml," in front of it. And then instead of insetting the string using innerHTML you can use `append()`.

I refactored the code a bit, but basically you had all the elements.

I hope that I understood your code correctly: the card should be a `<button>` itself. displaying an SVG image inside of it.

```js
// Data

let rank, suit;
let cardArray = [];

const images = {
  'A_S': '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><circle r="10" fill="blue" cx="10" cy="10" /></svg>',
  'A_C': '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><circle r="10" fill="green" cx="10" cy="10" /></svg>'
}
const ranks = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"];
const suits = ['S', 'C', 'D', 'H'];

var playgame = document.getElementById('playgame');
var master = document.getElementById('master');

// functions
const placeImage = function(index) {
  let button = document.createElement('BUTTON');
  button.className = 'card';
  //let imgDiv = document.createElement('div');
  let content = cardArray[index].image;
  button.append(content);
  master.append(button);
};

const card = function(rankarg, suitarg, imagearg) {
  this.rank = rankarg;
  this.suit = suitarg;
  this.image = imagearg;
};

let buildCardArray = function() {
  ranks.forEach(rank => {
    suits.forEach(suit => {
      let stringBuilder = `${rank}_${suit}`;
      let img = new Image();
      img.src = `data:image/svg+xml,${images[stringBuilder]}`;
      let thisCard = new card(rank, suit, img);
      thisCard.toString = function() {
        return stringBuilder;
      }
      cardArray.push(thisCard);
    });
  });
};

buildCardArray();

// Event listeners
playgame.addEventListener('click', e => {
  placeImage(1);
});
```

```css
button.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  border: thin solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonDiv">
  <button id="playgame">Are you feeling lucky?</button>
</div>
<div id="master"></div>
```